# System of differential equation in three variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have the following system of differential equations:

$$ m \sqrt{y(x, z)} + \left( \frac{nz}{\sqrt{1-y(x, z)}} + \frac{mx}{\sqrt{y(x, z)}}\right)y_{1}(x,z) = 0 $$

$$ n \sqrt{1-y(x, z)} + \left( \frac{nz}{\sqrt{1-y(x, z)}} + \frac{mx}{\sqrt{y(x, z)}}\right)y_{2}(x,z) =0 $$

Here $y_1(x,z)$ and $y_2(x,z)$ are derivative of y(x,z) wrt x and z respectively.

I have to simultaneously solve these differential equation to get value of y(x, z)

How can I solve these system of equations?

Can I solve them separately, and get the expression of y(x, z) from each and then combine the two expression by averaging them?

Any resource or hints will be helpful.

Comment: @ElinaGilbert I corrected the formatting but the question still needs editing. You forgot the index of $y$ at most places in the equation. Please clear up your question.

Comment: $y_1$ and $y_2$ are not indexes but first order derivatives wrt 1st and 2nd elements (x and z) respectively.

Comment: @ElinaGilbert. You ask "How can I solve them?'. But solve for what ? Clarify what is known and what is unknown. If there is only one unknown $y(x,z)$ and two equations this is generally not possible.

Comment: @JJacquelin I have edited the question and clarified my query. Hopefully, it is more clear now. Thank you for pointing out my slackness.

Comment: It's a good thing that you can solve them separately. But what make you think that the two solutions be compatible one to the other ? Generally this is not the case. Whitout context it is impossible to say if the average of solutions or other combination might have a significance. Try and see.

Comment: @JJacquelin Thanks for the reply. It is actually my exact question. That if I do solve them separately and average the solution will it be compatible with when it had been solved simultaneously? Secondly, how to solve them simultaneously? Is there a method which can solve them as a system. I tried combining the equation and used legrange method (it gave me same answer as separate solving). Is there any other method?